# printing as the length of middle string in python

Tags: python

I've tried `sorted()` but no luck.
I need to solve this problem without using conditions or loops.

When this function is called, it should return a string of asterisks (*) that is the same length as the string argument with the median length.

```
def mid_string_of_stars(text1, text2, text3):

    maksimum=max(len(text1), len(text2), len(text3))

    minimum = min (len(text1), len(text2), len(text3))

    m=(maksimum+minimum)/2 

    middle_string='*'*m
    return middle_string
```

Comment: Your problem description is tough to follow, perhaps provide some sample inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: when I give 3 string parameters the function should print number of asterisks equal of the length of the middle string when string lengths are ordered in ascending or descending order.

Comment: You just repeated what you wrote above (which is difficult to follow), could you give an example of three strings you would pass in and what the resulting string would look like?

Comment: @sedavidw From what I understand, the function outputs the length of the median length string in asterisks.  If `dog`, `helicopter`, and `table` are the strings, the output is `*****`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you could solve this problem.

Using `sorted` and indexing seems like the simplest (in terms of the amount of code you need to write. Just sort the three lengths, then index to get the middle one:

```
def mid_string_of_stars(text1, text2, text3):
    order = sorted(map(len, (text1, text2, text3)))
    return '*' * order[1]
```

Another approach would just use arithmatic along with the minimum and maximum values you're currently calculating:

```
def mid_string_of_stars(text1, text2, text3):
    maximum = max(len(text1), len(text2), len(text3))
    minimum = min(len(text1), len(text2), len(text3))
    middle = len(text1) + len(text2) + len(text3) - minimum - maximum
    return '*' * middle
```

Another way or writing that last code would create a single variable with a tuple containing the three lengths, then use the `sum`, `min` and `max` on the tuple to avoid so much repetition:

```
def mid_string_of_stars(text1, text2, text3):
    lengths = (len(text1), len(text2), len(text3))
    return '*' * (sum(lengths) - min(lengths) - max(lengths))
```

Comment: appreciate the help. now I know what I skipped in my thinking process.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your code snippet provides the ***mean*** while the problem description asks for the ***median***. You have the right idea with sorted. You can pass the string inputs to an array and then use sort() to modify the list in-place (see https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) and then grab the length of the middle element. I see that you already know how to use len() and create string of '*' so you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be finding the mean of the max and min text lengths, which by no means would guarantee equalling the middle length.

You could try sorting the lengths of text, followed by selecting the middle value. For even numbers of string you could round this number and take either of the two middle, but that is your call.

This code worked for me:

```
text1 = 'hello'
text2 = 'my name'
text3 = 'is monty'

def mid_string_of_stars(text1, text2, text3):
    lengths = sorted([len(text1),len(text2),len(text3)])
    middle = round((len(lengths)-1)/2)
    middle_length = lengths[middle]

    middle_string = '*'*middle_length
    return middle_string
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
def mid_string_of_stars(text1, text2, text3):

    maksimum=max(len(text1), len(text2), len(text3))

    minimum = min (len(text1), len(text2), len(text3))

    m = len(text1) + len(text2) + len(text3) - maksimum - minimum 
    # so that m is actually one of len(text1) or len(text2) or len(text3)
    res = []
    i = 0
    while i<m:
        res.append('*')
        i = i + 1

    return ''.join(res)
```